# Getting incompatible debugger version error in eclipse PHP

Tags: php, eclipse

Getting incompatible debugger version
The remote debugger version might not match the expected protocol version 
(2006040705). Show error pop up after after every some time

I am using

Eclipse for PHP Developers

Version: Helios Service Release 1
Build id: 20100917-0705

Answer (score 16):

It seems to be a bug in Eclipse PDT and according to this report: 
[Bug 271071 - "Incompatible debugger version" when not debugging](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=271071), the bug seems to fix itself when you close ALL projects in the workspace and then reopen whichever you need.

Personally I have solved it by changing the debug ports in "Preferences -> PHP -> Debug -> Installed Debuggers", with these values:

**Zend Debugger (30000)**

**XDebug (19000)**

That Works for me, maybe you have to try another ports.

Regards

Comment: Good thinking! That error is annoying and I wasn't sure what exactly it was from (I don't use PHP debuggers so I never thought of it trying to connect to it) -- turned out it was trying to connect to Zend Debugger on port 10000 which is my SSH tunnel to Webmin on my server, so obviously not the correct protocol version lol

Answer (score 7):

I got same problem and the cause is related to the bittorrent / utorrent browser toolbar.
You should remove the toolbar and restart the browsers to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Changing default ZendDebugger and XDebug ports helps.

Answer (score 0):

simply close all running application and codes and restart the application again. It will run fine.