# Incompatible debugger version - error 2006040705

Tags: php, eclipse, xdebug

how to get rid of the following Incompatible debugger version error :

php.ini setting :

```
xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=10000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="C:\xampp\tmp"
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer, port were miss matching b/w php.ini and eclipse.

Comment: Give the port number to 9000. I changed `xdebug.remote_port=9000` and it works

Answer (score 3):

Check this at below link this help in my case too.

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551711/getting-incompatible-debugger-version-error-in-eclipse-php)
It seems to be a bug in Eclipse PDT and according to this report: Bug 271071 - "Incompatible debugger version" when not debugging, the bug seems to fix itself when you close ALL projects in the workspace and then reopen whichever you need.

Personally I have solved it by changing the debug ports in "Preferences -> PHP -> Debug -> Installed Debuggers", with these values:

Zend Debugger (30000)

XDebug (19000)

That Works for me, maybe you have to try another ports.

Comment: Switching ports worked for me.  The [default pydev port (5678)](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=How-to:Debug_Python_Scripts_with_Eclipse#Setting_the_remote_debugger_port_.28optional.29) was also being [used by MS Exchange](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/259369).

Answer (score 2):

With me it was an add-on in firefox interfering (the errors didn't show up when firefox was closed). I believe it was an add-on from muTorrent, named Conduit, but I deleted several at the same time. After this the error stopped showing up.

Comment: This fixed for me too, i had the debugger triggering when IE was on. I disabled every plugin in IE and this stopped pop out the debug dialog.

Answer (score 0):

The FF plugin muTorrent was my case too. Actually the muTorrent has a malicious behavior, during installation even I've unchecked all the extras   still all my browsers have the extension installed, My suggestion is to uninstall everything has to do with the program.